# ASP.NET MVC - compiler not updating global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was trying to make some changes to my global.asax.cs file, when I spotted, that after publishing my mvc application that file is not even touched by visual studio. Last modified date is from last week, while today I made a lot of changes to it. How do I force visual studio to actually do something useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the "Build Action" for the Global.asax is set to "Content". Open Visual Studio -> Right Click on Global.asax -> Build Action